# perform jquery only on submit

Tags: jquery, validation, if-statement

**WHAT I WANT TO DO**

I use the following script to validate a form submission. I have a textbox "#MemberIDs" that is dynamically populated with data, i.e. ",100,101,105". I want to remove the first comma when the form is submitted but not until the first "if statement" passes validation.

**THE PROBLEM**

Email validation works fine but the second "if statement" does not execute regardless if the the email passes or fails validation. If I remove the 2nd "if statement" and just use the replace script it will remove the comma regardless if the the email passes or fails validation.

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    var email = $('#Email').val();
    var email2 = $('#Email2').val();
    var pattern = /^\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i
    if (!pattern.test(email) || email != email2) {
        alert('You either entered an invalid E-mail address, or the \"Email\" and \"E-mail Confirm\" do not match.');
        e.preventDefault(e);
    }
    if ($("form").valid()) {
        var mid = $('#MemberIDs').val().replace(/^[,]/, '');
        $('#MemberIDs').val(mid);
    }
});
```

Comment: then it means that $('form').valid() returns false. So you need to read more about .valid() is it even exist.

Comment: You say your email validation works fine but how will that reg ex validate my _.agency_ email address?

Comment: Ok looks like valid() isn't what I want. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'll take a little look…

Comment: @DuncanTidd - thanks for bringing that to my attention. I will fix that by increasing the number of characters. Any thoughts on the problem I'm trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need the second if statement.
If the test passes the reg ex, then you can put the following actions into `else{}`.

Here's how I would go about it:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $('#Email').val();
    var email2 = $('#Email2').val();
    var pattern = /^\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i
    if (!pattern.test(email) || email != email2) {
        alert('You either entered an invalid E-mail address, or the \"Email\" and \"E-mail Confirm\" do not match.');
    }       
    else {
        var mid = $('#MemberIDs').val().replace(/^[,]/, '');
        $('#MemberIDs').val(mid);
        // form submission here? AjAX?
        $.ajax({
            // Whatever you need
        )}
    }           
});
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/et4y4sq3/)

Comment: Of course else{}! Need to restart the brain.  Thanks for your help. FYI for others - the jsfiddle might confuse  the solution. Using else statement works! Tanks for your time Duncan.